# How can I prevent Ctrl+C from "going outwards"?

Tags: shell, freebsd, signals, process-management

I want to run an interactive tool that can either exit by itself (when the tasks are done) or by me hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>. In this example, the tool consists of an `echo` and a `sleep` (thus it is not really interactive any more).

I need some more monitoring around it, so I would do

```
echo "$(date) Starting!" | tee -a myLog.log; \
echo "I NEED SOME TIME"; \
sleep 10; \
echo "$(date) Ended!" | tee -a myLog.log
```

But this only works if I do not press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> -- when I do, the last echo is not executed.

Can I somehow prevent the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> from propagating "outwards" to the overall process?

Working in a `sh` on a FreeBSD.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand you correctly:

```
#!/bin/sh
trap catchSigint INT
catchSigint(){
    echo
    echo "$(date) Interrupted" | tee -a myLog.log
    exit 1
}
echo "$(date) Starting!" | tee -a myLog.log
echo "I NEED SOME TIME"
sleep 10
echo "$(date) Ended" | tee -a myLog.log
```

See that we are trapping SIGINT (triggered by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>). If it is detected, then catchSigint terminates execution, logging "Interrupted". Else, "Ended" is logged.

Comment: My interpretation of the OP's question was that he wanted the ctrl-c to kill the sleep but not the script so he wanted the "Ended" in the log. This just means ignoring SIGINT, or at least not calling exit in the handler.

Comment: Exactly what I needed. @icarus, in this case it is the same -- I only want the time of the ending (that was missing in your script, quasímodo, I edited it) in the log, so the script can end that way.